# Editable WPF treeview item on doubleclick? (with styles?)

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm a bit of a WPF noob, so apologies for any inherent daftness in this question (!)

I'm trying to enable editing of WPF treeview labels with a doubleclick - I've googled around this, and it looks like the two ways of doing this are with a custom control or with a style which hides one of a TextBox/TextBlock.

Using a style to set the label to be a textBox based on a DataTrigger seems easy enough (eg 1 below), but it means that any time a row is selected, it's 'being edited'.

What I'd really like to do is to enable this (Transition to textbox) on a mousedoubleclick event, but it seems that EventTriggers can't be used in the manner below, because they're transient.  (It doesn't seem I can simply use the DoubleClick event in codebehind, because that doesn't (??) allow me to affect the displayed controls to show / hide the textboxes).

Using a full blown custom control seems like the alternative - there's an AAALMOST working example here ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/editabletextblock.aspx ), however it doesn't work in the presence of HierachicalDataTemplate clauses (and it doesn't look like a solution is forthcoming).

(eg 1 - switch from textblock to textbox when selected)

```
<Window x:Class="treetest.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:treetest"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EditableContentControl" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CompositeViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource=RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                 Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CompositeViewModel}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                
            </DataTrigger> 
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>  
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView Margin="12,12,115,12" Name="treeView1"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetRootData}"
              >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CompositeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource EditableContentControl}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5):

does it help:

```
        string name = "some name";
        var treeItem = new TreeViewItem()
            {
                Header = name,
            };
        var textBox = new TextBox()
            {
                Text = name,
            };
        treeItem.MouseDoubleClick += (o, e) =>
            {
                TreeItem.Header = textBox;
            };
        textBox.LostFocus += (o, e) =>
            {
                treeItem.Header = textBox.Text;
                name = textBox.Text;
            };
```

it quite simple and it works for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of triggering on IsSelected you trigger on a custom property of your bound data like IsEditing? You can then set IsEditing to true whenever you want to change to happen (i.e. in your case, when the mouse button is clicked).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [CallActionMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723947%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) from Blend. This special trigger lets you make a loose link between any event like double click and a method in your code behind.

If you prefer using a command then you can do the same with [InvokeCommandAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724018%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx). You can hook up any command to an event.