# Create an editable wpf treeview item

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm checking this page and I like the only answer there is.

[Editable WPF treeview item on doubleclick? (with styles?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715877/editable-wpf-treeview-item-on-doubleclick-with-styles)

But I don't like the idea to use c# lines, Might there be a possible to write that code using XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EventSetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms602396.aspx), or [AttachedBehavior](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/introduction-to-attached-behaviors/). But they are assumes that you need c# code-behind.

How to do it in XAML - hard to say. One more possible way - to use [x:Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms750494.aspx) clause to write c# code inside xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CheckBox in the XAML and using its IsChecked property change the Style to the Editable mode